How did running messengers/hikyaku in early medieval Japan compare to those in the Edo period?
I started researching running messengers in Japan after encountering this claim that, on poor or mountainous road conditions, human messengers were often faster than horses during the Edo period. This led me to another site that claimed these runners were called hikyaku and that they had begun operating in the Heian period, faced disruptions to their livelihood during the Muromachi, and rebounded in the Edo period.
When I tried to verify this claim, however, I mainly found sources that discuss the Edo era hikyaku. Wikipedia’s entry says hikyaku first appeared in the Kamakura period. Called Roppara hikyaku, they rode horses, had a relay system, and were bakufu-affiliated replacements for the ekirei messengers established by the ritsuryō codes. According to the main source for the Wikipedia page, “Urban Networks and Information Networks” by Katsuhisa Moriya in Tokugawa Japan: the Social and Economic Antecedents of Modern Japan:

Communication arrangements had existed since ancient times, and they
were maintained from the medieval period by a network of express
messengers, known as hikyaku. These messengers accumulated a long and
rich legacy. Having handled freight and letters, bills of exchange,
and cash during the medieval period, the hikyaku system naturally
attracted great official attention at the dawn of the early modern
period (Moriya 1991, 107).

The chapter goes on to describe Edo era hikyaku, who mostly operated along the Tōkaidō roadway linking Edo, Kyoto, and Osaka. There were different types of hikyaku but the chapter focuses on those that rode horses between a system of post towns, operated first by the Tokugawa bakufu and later privatized by large “express companies” and smaller businesses that ran specific routes or for specific daimyo. There were set departure times overseen by a sairyo or foreman.
Yet there are a fair number of images depicting the running hikyaku, who were supposedly best on mountain routes. The key traits of these runners were traveling in pairs in little more than loincloths and carrying poles with lanterns and bells to warn people out of their way. Given their costume was hardly protective, I can understand why they might not have operated during the most intense warfare of the medieval period.
However, it seems like at least the Kamakura period (1185-1333) would have been calm enough for them to operate. While there were certainly wars during this period, it also saw expanding trade networks. According to Ethan Isaac Segal, there were a fair number of traveling merchants in the late Heian/early Kamakura era who had the right to pass freely through toll barriers (Segal 2011, 83). Many of the documents translated as “bills of exchange” were written and backed by traveling merchants and were involved in legal disputes by at least 1278. (Segal, 173-175). Merchants also transported these bills, but they can't have been the sole means of transport since Moriya mentions medieval hikyaku carrying them. Finally, it's unlikely road conditions were better compared to the Edo era, so there would have been an available niche.
The passage from Moriya confirms that mounted hikyaku operated during the medieval period, but I am particularly interested in running message carriers—whether they were hikyaku or operated under another name—and how they compared to Edo era runners. Given the sparse information I’ve found already, I’d be happy with confirmation on whether they existed or not during the medieval period for a comparison. That said, if they did exist and the information is available, I would like to know how similar their organizational structure was to the Edo hikyaku with their system of stations, relays, and foremen overseeing departure times.
